# wso2 show all api list without login

Tags: api, wso2, store, wso2-api-manager

I have created 3 api, one with

```
owner=apicreator
visibility=public
```

and the others two with

```
owner=admin
visibility="restricted by role".
```

Once I opened the store home page the only api visible is the one created with apicreator, then when I logged in as admin I can see the other two apis (final count of 3).

Is it possible to show all the api (doesn't matter by the owner or creator) in the store home page, without login?

Is there any configuration change to apply or any change in the jaggery code(I don't want to change the visibility)?

Thank you in advance

Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to show all the api (doesn't matter by the owner or
>   creator) in the store home page, without login?

If an API's visibility is based on roles, how do you expect API Store to show it to public?

Once a user logged in to the API Store only, we can identify their roles and based on that, API will be visible to him

Comment: ok, yes you're right the only way is to change the "visibility".